# flatlist images flashing when mutating data using SWR

Tags: react-native, swr

I am fetching an array of posts using SWR in a React native app and then displaying the data using React Native's flatlist.

When a user clicks a like button on an item, a function is called and the data is mutated on the server and the cache is updated to reflect the updated data.

The issue is when the data is mutated and revalidated, it causes the flat list to re-render and the images to flash.

I have tried using useCallback to wrap the function and React.memo to wrap the renderItem, but neither are fixing the issue.

I've also made sure the keyExtractor is using a unique value.

Here is my code:

```
export function PostList() {
  const { mutate } = useSWRConfig();
  
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    `${process.env.SERVER_API}/posts?userId=1`,
    fetcher
  );

  if (error)
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>failed to load</Text>
      </View>
    );
  if (!data)
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>loading...</Text>
      </View>
    );


  async function likePost(postId) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.SERVER_API}/likePosts`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({ postId, userId: 1 }),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
      }
      console.log("data", data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("There was a problem!");
    }
    return data;
  }

  const onClick = useCallback((postId) => {
      const options = {
        rollbackOnError: true,
      };

      mutate(
        `${process.env.SERVER_API}/posts?userId=2`,
        likePost(postId),
        options
      );
  }, []);

  const Item = React.memo(
    ({ id, title, image, categories}) => (
      <>
        <RecipeCard
          id={id}
          title={title}
          image={image}
          onClick={onClick}
        />
      </>
    )
  );

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }: any) => (
    <Item
      index={index}
      id={item.post_id}
      title={item.title}
      image={item.image
      categories={item.categories}
    />
  );

  const keyExtractor = (item) => item.post_id;

  return (
    <>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Keys shouldn't be random. If you keep them random, then on every render if the new key is different, react will have to re-render the whole element.

Comment: Try using recipe_id as key in keyextractor

Comment: Thanks @TayyabMazhar, I tried, but still the same issue.